# Word for "communicating one's feelings"

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> [...] to her is the thing I should have done back then.

I'm not particularly referring to love. It could also be a lesser feeling like affection or gratitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Open*** is the verb.

> *trans. (refl.).* To reveal or confess one's intentions or feelings. [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/131700?rskey=373GVH&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)

---

> Opening myself to her is the thing I should have done back then.

---

As a phrase, you can consider ***open up (to somebody)***.

> *intr.* To talk; esp. to declare one's thoughts or feelings, to unburden oneself [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/131700?rskey=373GVH&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)

---

> Opening up to her is the thing I should have done back then.

Answer (score -2):

What about the simple and exact *express*..?

*Express my gratitude to her is the thing I should have done back then.*

or, in more direct form -

*I should have expressed my gratitude to her back then.*

Comment: Curious why this is voted down?